# How to automatically fill span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in my web application with these tags:

```
<p>
    <label>Imponibile</label>
    <span class="field">
 <input type="text" name="imponibile" id="imponibile" class="width100" value="<?php echo  $pagamento['imponibile'] ?>"  />
 </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Iva %</label>
    <span class="field">
 <input type="text" name="iva" id="iva" class="width100" value="<?php echo  $pagamento['iva'] ?>"  />
 </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Totale</label>
    <span class="field" id="totale"> 0.0
 </span>
</p>
```

I would like that when the user enters the value of Iva % and Imponibile then the span totale should fill with a value given by a formula on the previuous tag. Here is what I've written:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  ...
  $("#totale").text($("#imponibile").val()+($("#imponibile").val() * $("#iva").val()));   
  });
</script>
```

which does not work. I have no experience of JS or jQuery.
Any help?

Code:
    
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: "-80:+0",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

jQuery("#form1").validate({

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        //check whether chosen plugin is initialized for the element
        if (element.data().chosen) { //or if (element.next().hasClass('chosen-container')) {
            element.next().after(error);} 
        else {element.after(error);}
    },

    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        id_progetto: "required",
        imponibile: "required",
        data_pagamento: "required",
        metodo_pagamento: "required",
        tipo_pagamento: "required",
        iva: "required",
        is_pagato: "required",
    }, 

    messages: {
        id_progetto: "Specifica il progetto di riferimento",
        imponibile: "Inserisci il valore dell'imponibile del pagamento",
        data_pagamento: "Inserisci la data del pagamento",
        metodo_pagamento: "Seleziona un metodo di pagamento",
        tipo_pagamento: "Seleziona la tipologia del pagamento",
        iva: "Inserisci il valore corretto dell'IVA",
        is_pagato: "Indica se il pagamento è stato versato",

    }
});

var value = parseFloat($("#imponibile").val()) + (parseFloat($("#imponibile").val()) * parseFloat($("#iva").val()));
$("#totale").text(value);

jQuery(".submit").click(function(){
    if(jQuery("#form1").valid())
    jQuery("#caricamento").css("display","block");
});

});
```

Comment: Can you correct the title `hot to automatically file span text` I don't think hot is the word you wanted but I am not sure what you really wanted to say

Comment: Going to have a wild stab at `how` and `fill`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseFloat` on numeric values:

```
var value = parseFloat($("#imponibile").val()) + (parseFloat($("#imponibile").val()) * parseFloat($("#iva").val()));

$("#totale").text(value);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: thanks but I'm afraid I am putting it in the wrong position inside the php file... when the page is loaded I get "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"...

Comment: @LoryLory - Have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: @LoryLory Add `jQuery` on the page

Comment: yes yes...I have loaded jQuery because I use other jQuery functions and they work...this does not. I'll write the code on my question before

Comment: The last }); is too much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger this calculation on change of input

```
 $('#iva').on('input',function(){
    var imponibile = parseInt($("#imponible").val(), 10);
    var iva = parseInt($("#iva").val(), 10);

    // calculate
    var totale = imponibile * iva;
    // output to frontend
    $("#totale").text(totale); 
});
```

Comment: I can't do that...the "totale" value should be shown as sson as the user has entered the other values...

Comment: Well you could use the change event: $( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
}); But then the calculation is made everytime a user changes the value

Comment: yes...this is what I want: each time the values are changed, then the calculus of the new total is re-made

Comment: It doesn't work sorry...when I load the page I get "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" on this line

Comment: $('#iva').on('input',function(){

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80785/discussion-between-m1crdy-and-lory-lory).

Answer (score 0):

You never assign any oninput or any other event to your input.

```
function Total(){
    var tIva = $('#iva');
    var tImp = $('#imponibile');
    var tT = $('#totale');

    tT.html((parseFloat(tIva.val()) + parseFloat(tImp.val())).toFixed(2))
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#iva').bind('input', function(){Total()})
    $('#imponibile').bind('input', function(){Total()})
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vdfjrhu9/

Or here with jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/vdfjrhu9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $('#iva').on('input',function(){
    var value = parseFloat($("#imponibile").val()) +      (parseFloat($("#imponibile").val()) * parseFloat($("#iva").val()));
$("#totale").text(value);
});
</script>
```

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qjoqmgcm/)

Comment: I doesn't work, I'm sorry...I keep on getting this damned error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" on this line $('#iva').on('input',function(){

Comment: have you tried **jQuery** instead of **$** @LoryLory

Comment: ok, I don't get the error anymore but the value of "totale" remains 0 even after entering the iva value...

Comment: **$pagamento['imponibile']** checkout this value is it a value greater than zero @LoryLory

Comment: Try this above the call: window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

Comment: alert($("#imponibile").val());  Can you run this in your script and confirm it@LoryLory